# React Native Bottom Tab Navigation content styling

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am coding an app with a bottom Tab Navigator nested within a Stack Navigator, I am trying to target the content styling for all the screen within this Tab.Navigator but the commands I am using are not working

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigator(){
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      // tabBarOptions={{
      //   style: {backgroundColor: "#511cff"} // deprecated metro says to place it into screenOptions under tabBarStyle
      // }}
      screenOptions={{
        // headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#2f28fc" },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#F8F2DA",
        tabBarOptions:{
          contentStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
          sceneContainerStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#2f28fc",
          contentStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
          sceneContainerStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
        },
        contentStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
        sceneContainerStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"},
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#2f28fc" },
            headerTintColor: "#F8F2DA",
            sceneContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#511cff" }
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            name='ExpensesView'
            component={TabNavigator}
            screenOptions={{
              sceneContainerStyle:{ backgroundColor: "#511cff" },
              contentStyle: {backgroundColor:"#511cff"}
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

From looking through here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8076
I think the solution would be to use the sceneContainerStyle property within Navigator like so:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  sceneContainerStyle= {{
    backgroundColor: "#511cff"
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by using sceneContainerStyle property outside of the screenOptions property. Why they have moved it out of the screenOptions for just TabNavigator is a mystery, but it works.

CODE:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    headerShown: false,
  })}
  sceneContainerStyle={styles.sceneStyle}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation for you and found that you syntax is not valid.
Their is nothing like tabBarOptions in it.

here's the link of how we can use the options in tab Bar
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options

Hope this will help u.

Comment: I was trying to style the content of the tab navigator screens with the screenOptions property but I was unsuccessful.
I found this issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8076 on React Navigation Git, so I used sceneContainerStyle property instead

Comment: maybe it was depreciated in the new update cz i couldn't it in docs.